# How to improve reading (listing) 25k of small files from s3 by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, minio

I have 25,000 small files on Minio S3 to parse.

```
df = spark.read.text("s3a://bucket/*/*/file*.txt").withColumn("path", input_file_name())
# parsing
# writing to parquet
```

Parsing and writing to parquet is fast. But listing files by s3 api took about 40 minutes.
Question, how to make listing faster?

I using Spark 3.1.1 with Hadoop 3.2.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but conceivably you could create an S3 inventory report and work off of that.

Comment: I don`t using Amazon S3, I using Minio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really fast:

```
    df = spark.read.option("pathGlobFilter", "file*.txt"). \
    option("recursiveFileLookup", "true"). \
    text(f"s3a://bucket/").withColumn("path", input_file_name())
```